# Opening High Res Images on Lumia 1020

Tags: windows-phone-8

Any one know if there is a way of opening the high res original photo stored on a 1020 in an app? 
 are stored in pairs, the post-processed lower res one and original high res one which seems to be hidden from the phone api.

You can get to it when connected to a pc.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to access the original (41MP) image from code on the device.

I've heard lots of people complaining about this, so maybe this will change in the future. But for now it's not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/69ca308b-ff37-4f27-a6b0-b7559bbdfa33/programmatically-access-high-resolution-images-on-lumia-1020-1520?forum=wpdevelop

Looks like Nokia and MS have decided to keep it blocked to 3rd party apps for stability reasons. However i have heard 'Open in Nokia Camera' option makes native Nokia Camera to access 38MP pics.

Makes sense as this app clicks (writes) it, so it will have surely read permissions.